# Foundation 6 Reveal shift

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 6 reveal modal window and when you click to open part of the scroll bar leaves where my fixed nav is and shifts content to the right about 5 to 10 px

```
<a class="button" data-open="exampleModal1">View users</a>


<!-- This is the first modal -->
<div class="reveal" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
  <h1>Awesome!</h1>
  <p class="lead">Users List!</p>  
  <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal" type="button">
    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know issue, see discussion [here](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7831).
I use the following Foundation CSS overwrite solution:

```
body.is-reveal-open {overflow: auto !important; height: auto; position: relative;}
.reveal-overlay {overflow: initial !important; position: absolute;}
```

Comment: that solved the shift but it forces the window to top or bottom on close or open

Comment: I adopted the same solution on my site and it works 100%, not sure what causes your new problem. Make sure these overwrite CSS settings are loaded after Foundation CSS.

Comment: It works as long as the modal does not exceed the viewport height. This solution prevents any vertical scrolling.