# Foundation 6 Reveal Modal + Slick Slider Not Playing Nicely

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, slick.js

OK, so I have noticed this on a couple of sites that I am building right now, but for debugging purposes let's use this one; http://bsmgpdev.org.uk/

When viewing on a mobile (iPhone X currently here) and clicking either the search or menu icon, the slider seems to jump/expand horizontally as the reveal modal opens/closes.

Now, I'm entirely sure it's something I've done, or missed, I don't doubt that for one minute, but could anybody point me in the right direction or (even better) tell me how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you fix this on the site you gave as an example? I don't see any horizontal sliding/expanding.

Comment: Hi, no it is not fixed. What are you currently viewing on?

Comment: I tested iPhone X through dev-tools and on a physical Samsung S8. I think I can see what you mean now though. For me, some elements like the logo and menu shift to the right when the fixed reveal is opened/closed which can be due to a known issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435055/foundation-6-reveal-shift

Comment: I don't think it relates to this known issue, although similar. The reveal modal is conflicting with Slick Slider, as soon as I remove that it works fine. It appears to be forcing the slider to the full width of ALL slides (1500px in my case).

Comment: So I have removed Slick from the home page, and replaced with Zurbs 'Orbit Slider', and all is well. I'm not entirely sure why I was using Slick in the first place, seeing as Orbit comes bundled. Thanks for taking a few moments to look btw :)